# Relacionamento OneToMany / ManyToOne TypeOrm não está salvando a chave estrangeira. O valor vai como NULL

Tags: postgresql, typescript, typeorm

Bem, estou usando TypeOrm no meu projeto de TCC. É algo bem simples, nada muito complexo. Estou usando o PostgreSQL para salvar os dados, no banco eu tenho apenas duas tabelas, uma chamada **usuarios** e outra chamada **tanque**. O que eu preciso é que quando um usuário cadastrar um tanque, na tabela seja registrado o id dele. Mas, a coluna "*id_user*" na tabela **tanque**, não registra o *id* do usuario, o campo fica **NULL**. Segue abaixo as relações e rotas que tenho feito.

**User.ts**

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToMany, JoinColumn, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from 'typeorm'
import Tanque from './Tanque';

@Entity('usuario')
export default class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: string;

    @Column({
        length: 50,
        unique: true,
    })
    nome: string;

    @Column({
        length: 50,
    })
    cidade: string;

    @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_At' })
    createdAt: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn({ name: 'update_At' })
    updateAt: Date;

    @OneToMany(() => Tanque, tanque => tanque.user, {
        cascade: ['insert', 'update']
    })
    @JoinColumn()
    tanque: Tanque[];
}
```

**Tanque.ts**

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, ManyToOne, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn, JoinColumn } from 'typeorm'
import User from './User';

@Entity('tanque')
export default class Tanque {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: string;

    @Column({
        length: 50,
        unique: true
    })
    nome_tanque: string;

    @Column()
    altura: string;

    @Column()
    largura: string;

    @Column()
    comprimento: string;

    @Column()
    phAgua: string;

    @Column()
    quantPeixe: string;

    @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_At' })
    createdAt: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn({ name: 'update_At' })
    updateAt: Date;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.tanque)
    @JoinColumn()
    user: User;

}
```

Rotas:

**usuario.routes.ts**

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { validate } from 'class-validator'
import Usuario from '../models/User';

const usuarioRouter = Router();

usuarioRouter.post('/', async (request, response) => {
    try {
        const repo = getRepository(Usuario);

        const { id, nome, cidade } = request.body;

        const user = repo.create({
            id,
            nome,
            cidade
        });

        const erros = await validate(user);

        if (erros.length === 0) {
            const res = await repo.save(user);
            return response.status(201).json(res);
        }
        return response.status(400).send();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('err.message :>> ', err.message);
        return response.status(400).send();
    }
});

export default usuarioRouter;
```

**tanque.routes.ts**

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import Tanque from '../models/Tanque';

const classRouter = Router();

classRouter.post('/', async (request, response) => {
    try {
        const repo = getRepository(Tanque);
        const res = await repo.save(request.body);
        return response.status(201).json(res)

    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Mensagem de erro :>> ', err.message);
        return response.status(400).send();
    }
});

export default classRouter;
```

Comment: Comigo aconteceu a mesma coisa, esperando uma resposta